# There exists an expansion function from $S_1 \to S_1$ that is continuous and has no fixed points?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, continuity, fixed-points

If $S_1 = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^2 : \|x\| = 1 \}$ is it possible to construct a function $f: S_1 \to S_1$ that is continuous and for all $x, y \in S_1$ we have $|f(x)-x| \ge \dfrac{1}{10}$ and $|f(y) - f(x)| \ge \dfrac{11}{10} |x-y|$ ?

The first I think that garantees no fixed point, but in my mind I cannot create a function that is a expansion because it has to be in $S_1$.

Comment: What does $S_1$ stand for?

Comment: sphere in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: I don't think the expansion condition can ever be satisfied, irrespective of the first condition.  It implies injectivity but also implies (and I know that this is not rigorous) that the mapping will "wrap around" the circle at faster than unit speed, and so the image will intersect itself, contradicting the injectivity.

Comment: If $x$ and $y$ are antipodal points, and so $|x-y|$ has its maximum value, it is not possible that $|f(y)-f(x)| \ge \frac{11}{10}|x-y| > |x-y|$.

Comment: another option is to notice that your second condition implies $f$ is a homeomorphism.  Then $\overline f =\frac{1}{f}$ (working in $\mathbb C$ instead of $\mathbb R^2$: this reads as conjugation composed with $f$) is an orientation reversing homeomorphism so it has exactly $2$ fixed points $z, z'$ i.e. we have $\big \vert  f(z)-f(z')\big \vert = \big \vert \overline f(z)-\overline f(z')\big \vert = \big \vert z - z'\big \vert$, ref https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2163688/an-orientation-reversing-homeomorphism-of-the-circle-has-two-fixed-points-and-ro/